# NetLogo netlogo-headless.sh file location

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, netlogo, behaviorspace

I am attempting to run Netlogo on headlessly using linux in order to send a job to a cluster.  I have never used linux before, but I am attempting to follow the directions here (http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Running-NetLogo-Headless-in-Behaviorspace-Sample-code-td4862232.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 1  
#SBATCH -c 7
module load netlogo/5.3.1-64
~/netlogo-5.3.1-64/netlogo-headless.sh \
-- model /cluster/home/rfuda01/UM_model.nlogo \
--experiment UM
--table /cluster/home/rfuda01/UM_test.csv
```

When I submit the job, the output file contains an error message saying:

```
line 7: /cluster/home/rfuda01/netlogo-5.3.1-64/netlogo-headless.sh: No such file or directory
```

I see that this file is not located in the folder I specified, but every example that I've looked at for using NetLogo on a cluster refers to this script.  Where can I find the correct path to this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`netlogo-headless.sh` was inadvertently removed from the Linux install in 5.3.0: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/979

For now, you can use [5.2.1](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.2.1/).

Actually, you can probably just take the `netlogo-headless.sh` from a 5.2.1 download and put it in 5.3.1 without problems, but I haven't tested this.

Edit: Taking the old `netlogo-headless.sh` should work if you put it in the `app/` directory, under the main NetLogo directory. Thanks Nicolas!

Comment: Yes, using an old `netlogo-headless.sh` will work, but you have to run it from the `app/` directory, under the main NetLogo directory.

Comment: I found the headless script, but I am now getting a new error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/nlogo/headless/main`  I have created a new question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266666/java-error-when-trying-to-run-netlogo-headlessly-on-a-cluster)